# C# ignoring "duplicates" in a data table

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a datatable from some source which the structor

bookid   title  author

The table can contain the same book (repeated) if the book has several authors. Like

```
Book id    title    author    
32         Book1    P. Samsom
45         Book34   R. Englund
45         Book34   H. Granger
56         Book45   F. Lister
```

etc.

Now the second and third book are the same ( it has 2 authors). When displaying the table (which can contain thousands items) I don't want to display the same book twice or more. It 's just enough with displaying one of them (I don't care).

Doing a Select distinct on the table won't help here. Doing a select distinct ignoring the author works, but I need at least ONE author. So what I want to do is to find the most effective way to just create a new table or view from this one which ignores any "duplicated" item keeping at least one author.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var books = Books.GroupBy(x=>x.Title).Select(x=>x.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thnx. With some changes it works: 
var books = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x.Field<Int32>("bookId")).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();

Answer (score 0):

```
var result =  books.GroupBy(b => b.bookid)
                   .Select(g => 
                        new { 
                            id = g.Key, 
                            title = g.First().title, 
                            authors = g.Select(a=>a.author).ToList() 
                        })
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: @downvoter, care to comment? or not enough justification to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`DistinctBy` from [MoreLINQ](http://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq)

```
var results = books.DistinctBy(x => x.title).ToList();
```